# Magento2 Fatal error due to not found interface in indexinterface.php

Tags: magento2

Fatal error: `Interface 'Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View\ViewInterface' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\module-wishlist\Controller\IndexInterface.php on line 15`

Comment: can you upload IndexInterface.php in your question

Comment: <?php
/**
 *
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Magento\Wishlist\Controller;

use Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View\ViewInterface;

/**
 * Interface \Magento\Wishlist\Controller\IndexInterface
 *
 */
Interface IndexInterface extends \Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface, ViewInterface
{
}